# Azure SQL vs Azure Database for MySQL

Tags: paas, azure-sql-database, azure-database-mysql

Now that Azure has started to provide Preview version of PaaS version of MySQL, how do I do an Apples to Apples comparison of Azure SQL and Azure MySQL from a Cost perspective?

In AWS RDS world, both SQL Server and MySQL are tied to compute units. While Azure SQL does Pricing Calculation based on DTUs (proportional to # of Transactions per second?) while "Azure Database for MySQL" does based on # of compute units + Storage.

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL DB uses "Database Transaction Units" for determining performance and Azure DB for MySQL uses "Compute Units".  Both are a blended measure of CPU/RAM however DTUs include disk IO performance whereas Compute Units do not.  Azure DB for MySQL gives you the option to choose your Disk IO performance in IOPS in the Standard and eventually Premium tiers.

Comment: Thanks. But If I have an RDBMS use case, can I choose between SQL and MySQL purely from a cost perspective (provided Performance is a given)? In AWS,  it is more straight forward both do it on the basis of IOPS / CPU / Memory.

Comment: While not perfect, the closest way to match would be to compare a Azure DB for MySQL Standard 100 to an Azure SQL DB Standard 100 elastic pool, testing on a single database.  Ensure your provisioned storage is as close as possible as well to get a closer comparison.